# How to change the value of actionButton using selectInput?

Tags: r, shiny

I'd like to create a situation where actionButton and selectInput influence each other. For example, I'd like to create a situation when the value of the selectInput changes the value of the actionButton.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput("select", "Select Input", choices = c(" ", "A", "B")),
      actionButton("action", "Action Button")
    ),
    mainPanel(
      textOutput("out1"),
      textOutput("out2")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  rv <- reactiveValues(count = 0)
  output$out1 <- renderText({
    paste("Action Button: ", input$action)
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$select, {
    if (input$select == "A") rv$count <- rv$count + 1
  })
  
  output$out2 <- renderText({
    paste("Select Input: ", rv$count)
  })
}

options(shiny.autoreload = TRUE)
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

In this example, [(thanks to this answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68147493/how-to-use-selectinput-like-an-actionbutton/68147563#68147563), the values change independently. I've tried to create a common value, but it doesn't seem to update.

I attempted to try updating the value using this  `updateActionButton(session, "action", "Action Button")`

But selectInput does not change the value of the actionButton. I'd like to find a way to make that happen.

Comment: So action button value should always copy select input value ?

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just use `rv$count` in Action button text as well?

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput("select", "Select Input", choices = c(" ", "A", "B")),
      actionButton("action", "Action Button")
    ),
    mainPanel(
      textOutput("out1"),
      textOutput("out2")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  rv <- reactiveValues(count = 0)
  output$out1 <- renderText({
    paste("Action Button: ", rv$count)
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$select, {
    if (input$select == "A") rv$count <- rv$count + 1
  })
  
  output$out2 <- renderText({
    paste("Select Input: ", rv$count)
  })
}

options(shiny.autoreload = TRUE)
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: This works! I was wondering whether updateSelectInput would do  it.

Comment: You mean `updateActionButton` ? I don't know if that can be used to change the count here.